# how to get XmlElement of unmarshaled java object

Tags: java, jaxb

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Item", propOrder = {
"code",
"name",
"price"
})
@XmlRootElement(name="inventory")
public class Item {

@XmlElement(name="catalog_num", required = true)
protected String code;

@XmlElement(name="catalog_descrip", required = true)
protected String name;

@XmlElement(name="prod_price")
protected double price;


public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

JAXBContext databaseJC = JAXBContext.newInstance(Item.class);
    Unmarshaller databaseUnmarshaller = databaseJC.createUnmarshaller();
    File databaseXML = new File("src/forum6838882/database.xml");
    Item item = (Item) databaseUnmarshaller.unmarshal(databaseXML);
```

My question is:
How could I get the `@XmlElement(name="catalog_num", required = true)` from item object. I need know the `name="catalog_num"` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) does not provide an API to introspect the metadata.  You can however use the Java Reflection APIs ([`java.lang.reflect`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html)) to get the annotations and examine them yourself.

**Demo**

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Field field = Item.class.getDeclaredField("code");
        XmlElement xmlElement = field.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);
        System.out.println(xmlElement.name());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
catalog_num
```